# How are constants defined and used in PHP?

Tags: php

my pages ref this line

require_once(LIBDIR."client.php");

where and how do I define the LIBDIR variable?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

well it should have been defined before using it, e.g:

```
define("LIBDIR", "/usr/foo/bar/");
```

if you use an unescaped string like LIBDIR, it may be a constant. if it was not declared as a constant, depending on your php-settings, it may be automatically castet as a constant.

Comment: thank you. I found it.  there were multiple require_once's that finally tracked back to it.